# Exact Decimal value as required

Tags: python, decimal

> Input:

```
from decimal import *
k=10
for i in range(k):
    getcontext().prec=i+1
    print(Decimal(103993)/Decimal(33102))
```

> Output

```
3  # for k=0
3.1
3.14
3.142
3.1416
3.14159
3.141593 # for k=6
3.1415927
3.14159265
3.141592653
```

I need the 7th term in output(for k=6) to be exactly 3.141592,

for k=20 the value should be 3.14159265301190260407

103993/33102 keeping this fraction constant(this shouldn't be changed in the input)

Comment: What's the actual question? (i.e. I see no question mark)

Comment: I need the 7th term in output(for k=6) to be exactly 3.141592,

Comment: Why don't you just get the value for `k+1` and clip the `Decimal.as_tuple()` value?

Comment: This will take too long...

Answer (score 1):

> I need the 7th term in output(for k=6) to be exactly 3.141592,

The reason you're seeing `3.141593` is that the value is being rounded to the nearest number with six decimal digits. To change the rounding mode, set `getcontext().rounding` as required.

[The available modes are](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context):

- ROUND_CEILING (towards Infinity),
- ROUND_DOWN (towards zero),
- ROUND_FLOOR (towards -Infinity),
- ROUND_HALF_DOWN (to nearest with ties going towards zero),
- ROUND_HALF_EVEN (to nearest with ties going to nearest even integer),
- ROUND_HALF_UP (to nearest with ties going away from zero), or
- ROUND_UP (away from zero).
- ROUND_05UP (away from zero if last digit after rounding towards zero would have been 0 or 5; otherwise towards zero)

To truncate the number, round towards zero.

Comment: @Ajay: How is truncation different from rounding towards zero?

Comment: So which option actually does what the OP asks for?

Comment: so which mode should i use now

Answer (score 0):

use

```
getcontext().rounding = ROUND_DOWN 

print(Decimal(103993)/Decimal(33102))
```

Hope this solves your problem.